# DMN, xml parsing, autogenerating tescase

Tags: xml, maven, parsing, junit5, dmn

A simple dmn model is created with one input and a decision for that . How to parse the xml of the dmn model using saxon and autogenerate testcase?

Answer (score 0):

To ***only parse*** the DMN model definition, you can use the marshalling modules of the [Drools DMN Engine](https://www.drools.org/learn/dmn.html), specifically the marshalling module is called [kie-dmn-backend](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/tree/main/kie-dmn/kie-dmn-backend), which uses plain java object definition from [kie-dmn-model](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/tree/main/kie-dmn/kie-dmn-model) module.

A good entry-point could be for you to have a look at [this JUnit test](https://github.com/kiegroup/drools/blob/c4b2737769bec57665e2b6aba2e8860cdb4b0fe8/kie-dmn/kie-dmn-backend/src/test/java/org/kie/dmn/backend/marshalling/v1_4/UnmarshalMarshalTest.java#L59-L64).

To auto-generate some test cases, specifically for Decision Tables, you might want to consider MC/DC algorithm such as the one [presented in this talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eQRDc6fq2yw).